# ODI : Integrate multiple .xml files using one created package

Tags: java, xml, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-data-integrator

i'm beginner at using ODI (Oracle Data Integrator) 11g.

I have multiple .xml files with same structure.

In ODI, i created package including many interfaces. I need to load all .xml files in one directory and store them into Oracle database. execute them all using my created package. My package works on one file. But my requirement is works on multiple .xml files.

Topology creation menu is working on only 1 file using JDBC driver.

**Here's my .xml files list. Note: file names with same format**

[image]

**Here's my ODI package. I created many interfaces on every table.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use variable for this . Create a script to store all files name in a text file then create a refresh variable to fetch values one by one & pass that variable in topology>Physical>XML, where we always specify the path of Xml.

Before doing that create a loop in a package for loading each file one by one.